# Getting authorization code has been used login or signup with facebook

Tags: php, laravel

When I am trying to login or signup through facebook(click on submit button) then this error
"Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad

> Request` response: {"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":36009,"f (truncated...)"
> occurs.

here is my **handlercallback** function in controller
**RegisterController.php**

```php
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
        {
            if($provider == 'twitter'){
                $token = Config::get('services.twitter.access_token');
                $secret = Config::get('services.twitter.access_secret');
                $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromTokenAndSecret($token, $secret);
            $user->getId();
            $dname = $user->getNickname();
            $uname = $user->getName();
            $email = $user->getEmail().$dname.$uname.'@twitter.com';
            $fname = $dname;
            $lname = $uname;
            }
            else{
          
                $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
            $user->getId();
            $dname = $user->getNickname();
            $uname = $user->getName();
            $email = $user->getEmail();
            $names = explode(" ", $uname);
            $fname = $names[0];
            $lname = $names[1];
            }
            // All Providers
    
            //$moble = $user->getPhone();
            $user->getAvatar();
            //print_r($moble); exit();
            $email_check = DB::table('userdetails')->where('email',$email)->where('provider',$provider)->get();
    
            if(count($email_check) > 0){
                Session::put('login_by',$email_check[0]->email);
                Session::put('userid',$email_check[0]->id);
                Session::put('firstname',$email_check[0]->firstname);
                Session::put('lastname',$email_check[0]->lastname);
                Session::put('useremail',$email_check[0]->email);
                Session::put('username',$email_check[0]->username);
                Session::put('groupid',$email_check[0]->groupid);
                Session::put('provider',$email_check[0]->provider);
                Session::put('is_login','1');
    
                return redirect('/');
    
            }
            else{
            $usergroup = DB::table('usergroup')->where('view_status','0')->get();
            print_r($usergroup);exit();
            return view('home.s-register',compact('dname','uname','email','usergroup','fname','lname','provider'));
            }
        }
```

template **s-register.blade.php**

```php
    <!-- Start Inner Contents -->
    
            <section class="login-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Invitation required</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="myaccount-body">
                <div class="myaccount-document">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3 >Please Sign Up</h3>
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <form name="form" method="post" action="/register/store">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <select name="grbid" class="form-control">
                                    @foreach($usergroup as $group)
                                    <option value="{{$group->id}}">{{$group->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                <br>
                                <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="geder" required="">
                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                                </select><br>
                                <input class="form-control" name="password" id="password" value="{{$provider}}" type="hidden">
                                <input class="form-control" name="provider" id="provider" value="{{$provider}}" type="hidden">
    
                                <label for="country">&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" checked="">&nbsp I accepts the <a href="{{url('/term-use')}}" target="_blank" required>Terms & Conditions.</a></label>
                                <p><button style="background-color: #37b2d6; padding: 5px 20px; border: 2px solid #37B2D6; color: #fff;" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="return Validate()" />SUBMIT</button></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- End Inner Contents -->
    @endsection
```

Comment: `twitter.access_token` for facebook login .?

Comment: no,in this line of code Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user(); we can replace $provider with facebook,gmail etc.

Comment: This error is what you get, when your app tries to exchange a code for a token for a second time. I don’t know Socialite, but you must be somehow triggering that functionality twice.